# How can I have a custom default scene in the three.js editor?

Tags: three.js, editor

I'm trying to use the Three.js editor to have the population participate in the town planning process. For that, I would like the editor to load with a 3D Version of the town, without the user having to load it manually. Clicking on "New" should also load that default model again.

I already copied the code on our server, it works. Which part of that code should I modify to do have the town model already loaded on startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for the threejs editor is available [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/editor) , you can just download it from it here,  add your code to display the default model at appropriate place and host it.

**Update 1: Adding a custom model in the Editor's Scene**

After reviewing the code of the `Editor.js` I found that you can add custom objects in the `scene`variable defined in the  `Editor` using the  `addObject()` function

I am assuming that you need to add an object which is exported out of blender in `.obj` format, but using this `addObject()` function you can add any object/mesh into the editor.

So in **index.html** add the following lines of code to add a model manually.

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
   loader.load( '../obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {
   object.position.y =0;
   editor.addObject( object );// THIS WAY YOU CAN MANUALLY ADD ANY MESH/OBJECT3D IN THE EDITOR

});
```

I have made and hosted an example [here](http://metalop.com/threejs_editor_custom_object/index.html) you can visit it and look around line 123 to see the custom code.

Comment: THank you, it may sound simple to you to find which part to modify to do that, but I started to read the code and couldn't find the place where I could automatically load my data on startup. If you can provide a snippet like onLoad (... my3DTown.js...) It would be really helpfull.

Comment: I modified the question to clarify things

Comment: Perfect :) Works like a charm. I now have to find out how to add a default light so that it's not black ^^

Comment: @matali: I'll give you a hint :) , just add the following code  below our previous custom code
 
`var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff);
editor.addObject( light );`

I have updated the file in the above link , you can have a look

Comment: Our Obj file is really big (80MB, hard for people without highspeed internet). You said that methode work for any Mesh, but I tried to load a CTM instead, but I couldn't get it with your method. I replaced THREE.OBJLoader with THREE.CTMLoader and changed the path to the ctm file. Loading from menu works and is really memory efficient (300MB for the whole City in 3D), so the CTM file is working. Could you solve that case too ?

Comment: @matali: yes you can add CTM file too , but just wanted to know , why use a 300MB CTM file when the obj is 80MB only?

Comment: @matali: long conversations are discouraged in the comments section so I have created a chat room ,kindly post the details here.http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47918/threejs-loading-different-models-in-threejs-scene