# How can I load a CTM file on startup in the three.js editor?

Tags: javascript, three.js, editor

Following this question : [How can I have a custom default scene in the three.js editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862226/how-can-i-have-a-custom-default-scene-in-the-three-js-editor) I tried to load a .ctm file. However, it seems to not use the same method. What must I do to get it load properly?

Comment: You have to show us what you are doing and how it is failing through a jsfiddle (probably) or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike and `.obj` file which probably contained information about the materials and geometries, the `CTM` file only contains information about the geometries.

So if you look at the code of the ThreeJs Editor [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/editor/js/Loader.js#L47) you will find that it loads the `geometries` from the `CTM` file and manually creates a `MeshPhongMaterial`  and then creates a mesh using these two and adds it to the `editor.scene`.

So the complete code will be something like this would be

```
var loaderCTM = new THREE.CTMLoader( true );


            loaderCTM.load( "models/camaro/camaro.ctm", function( geometry  ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    mesh.name = "camero";

                    editor.addObject( mesh );
                    editor.select( mesh );


            }, false );
```

I have also created a sample [here](http://metalop.com/threejs_editor_custom_object/ctm_loader.html) , you can look around at lines 124 to understand better.